# Changing properties of nth child in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation bar where I change "background-image" of menu items with nth-of-type CSS selector. Now, I want to change the picture of "background-image" when I hover to a definitive menu item. So, how can I change the "background-image" when I hover over the menu iteam using Javascript?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Islington College - Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">      
            nav ul li:nth-of-type(1){
                background-image: url('images/navigation/active_home.png');
                background-size: 40%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center top;
            }
            nav ul li:nth-of-type(2){
                background-image: url('images/navigation/courses.png');
                background-size: 40%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center top;
            }
            nav ul li:nth-of-type(3){
                background-image: url('images/navigation/lectures.png');
                background-size: 40%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center top;
            }
            nav ul li:nth-of-type(4){
                background-image: url('images/navigation/admission.png');
                background-size: 40%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center top;
            }
            nav ul li:nth-of-type(5){
                background-image: url('images/navigation/facilities.png');
                background-size: 40%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center top;
            }
            nav ul li:nth-of-type(6){
                background-image: url('images/navigation/contact.png');
                background-size: 40%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center top;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <header class="main_header">
            <figure id="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Islington College Logo">
            </figure> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" style="color: #EE2B32; padding-top: 43px;">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="courses.html" style="padding-top: 40px;">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="lectures.html" style="padding-top: 40px;">Lectures</a></li>
                    <li><a href="admission.html" style="padding-top: 34px;">Admission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="facilities.html" style="padding-top: 38px;">Facilities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html" style="padding-top: 41px;">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
            </nav>
     </header>
```

Comment: Can you not just use `nav ul li:nth-of-type(6):hover {background-image:x}` or just `nav ul li:hover {background-image:x}` in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do this with JavaScript? You should be able to use CSS:

```
nav ul li {
    background-size: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}

nav ul li:nth-of-type(1){
    background-image: url('images/navigation/active_home.png');
}
/* Like this */
nav ul li:nth-of-type(1):hover {
    background-image: url('images/navigation/active_home_hover.png');
}

nav ul li:nth-of-type(2){
    background-image: url('images/navigation/courses.png');
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(3){
    background-image: url('images/navigation/lectures.png');
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(4){
    background-image: url('images/navigation/admission.png');
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(5){
    background-image: url('images/navigation/facilities.png');
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(6){
    background-image: url('images/navigation/contact.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript Solution:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li:nth-child(1)').style.backgroundImage = "url('newbg.png')"
```

jQuery Solution:

```
$( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).css("backgroundImage", "url(newbg.png) no-repeat");
```

Comment: The return value of `querySelectorAll` doesn't have a `.style` property, and your post doesn't at all address how to accomplish this when the user hovers over the element.